# Checking the argument for calculation of the limit $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}} {x-\frac{\pi}{6}}$ = $\sqrt3 \over 2$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}} {x-\frac{\pi}{6}}$ = $\sqrt3 \over 2$

In computing this limit, i have used following steps:

$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}} {x-\frac{\pi}{6}}$

= $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2})} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$

= $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin(x)-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\frac{1}{2}} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$

= $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$

= $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})-\cos(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$            , because $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \cos(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$

= $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$

from here by the use of $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$ and theorem for limits of composite functions, it can be proved that:

$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}} {x-\frac{\pi}{6}}$ = $2 \over \sqrt3$, which is incorrect.

**Can anyone tell me, what i did wrong in this computation?**

It is likely that the assumption in this step is wrong:

$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})-\cos(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})} {\frac{\sqrt3}{2} (x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$            , because $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}} \cos(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$

If so, then can anyone tell me, what is wrong with this assumption?

Comment: In the process of calculating the limit,you can't just count one part and not the other

Answer (score 4):

We can not replace $\cos\dfrac\pi6$ with $\cos x$  just because $x\to\dfrac\pi6$

Better use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)  $$\sin x-\sin\dfrac\pi6=2\sin\dfrac{x-\dfrac\pi6}2\cos\dfrac{x+\dfrac\pi6}2$$

Then apply $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of that? This is a nice way. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot partially pass to the limit. See this example:
$$
1 = \lim_{x \to 1} 1 = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to1} \frac{1-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} 0 = 0.
$$
The error lies here:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to1} \frac{1-1}{x-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. But i dont think that is exactly what i did there. I think i replaced a constant function with a variable function.